# Manually knitting an Rmd file produces different results when the file is located at different place

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, blogdown

When writing a blog post, I often manually knit the document to examine the results, and the output used to be a normal `html_document`. However, after a recent update, manually knitting the document under a blogdown directory no longer produces the `html_document` output. Instead, it produces something like the following where latex formulas and figures are not displayed properly (taking the default content of an Rmd file as an example):

[image: 图片|690x369]

Here's the output of the "R Markdown" console in RStudio:

```
/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS 1.knit.md 
--to html4 
--from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash 
--output 1.html~ 
--lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/bookdown/rmarkdown/lua/custom-environment.lua 
--lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua 
--lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua 
--wrap preserve -M link-citations=true 
--standalone 
--section-divs 
--template /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/blogdown/resources/template-minimal.html 
--no-highlight 
--include-in-header /tmp/RtmphBPBhs/rmarkdown-str73fd791178f2.html 
--mathjax
```

If I knit the same document outside a blogdown directory, then the resulting output is as expected:

[image: 图片|690x370]

And the output of the "R Markdown" console is:

```
/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS 1.knit.md 
--to html4 
--from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash 
--output 1.html 
--lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua 
--lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua 
--self-contained 
--variable bs3=TRUE 
--standalone 
--section-divs 
--template /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html 
--no-highlight 
--variable highlightjs=1 
--variable theme=bootstrap 
--include-in-header /tmp/RtmpXfya1w/rmarkdown-str724a4171c407.html 
--mathjax 
--variable 'mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
```

What happens when I click the "knit" button in RStudio? How to adjust the behaviour so that when knitting the document in a blogdown directory produces an html_output file?

Answer (score 0):

The First .Rmd might just be a simple YAML syntax error, make sure you don't have ANY extract white spaces anywhere. maybe even post the code you are using.

[what happens when we render](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/rmarkdown-process.html) and [different build methods for blogdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/methods.html)

[Note that the minimum requirement for any R Markdown website is that it have an index.Rmd file as well as a _site.yml file. If you execute the rmarkdown::render_site() function from within the directory containing the website, the following will occur](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/rmarkdown-site.html)

In my experience I used a few different commands to help render individual .Rmd files inside blogdown, and then you have to run other commands to render the entire blogdown website for all the content to be rendered properly into their respective directories.

`blogdown::serve_site()` will render everything in the blogdown directory and allow it to be hosted for a website

`rmarkdown::render()` is ran when you knit, but I think you can render individual files with it as well.

`rmarkdown::render_site()` and this renders the entire site

You will have to look into each function more specifically to see if any help with your issue, it's been a minute since I edited my Blogdown site.